# earth plugin update

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is there any way to ensure that a user will view my html-embedded GE scene with "sufficiently" up-to-date version of Google Earth plug?

And possibly to initiate an update on his machine?

Example - using  `_...ge.getPluginVersion()..._` it is detected that the user has an "obsolete" (whatever it means, lets say 5.xx) GE plug version.
What action to take/where to redirect the user to update the plugin?

Logical choice -
 http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/earth/explore/products/plugin.html 
just indicates that there *is* a plugin installed, but does not seem to provide an option to update it...

Sorry for probably trivial question, but found no answer so far...

Regards

IK

Answer (score 1):

The API as you noted allows you to detect the version number of plugin in the client web browser which you could popup a window with message that the version of Google Earth/plugin is too old with link to upgrade.

But you cannot force or initiate an update from an external web page using the Google Earth API. This would have to be done by the plug-in itself.

Your html-embedded GE app can only respond to the version of the plugin and act accordingly. For example, if Plugin was really old such as v5.1 then the gx:Track extension would not be supported. Just like users running old web browsers you'll find a few users still running GE 5.x and 4.x in their browsers and a web-defined GE API webapp would have to accomodate what KML features to utilize accordingly.

Your web app could encounter users with GE plugins as old as GE 5.0 but the vast majority would be 6.x and 7.0.